# Find the number (count) and price of new and repeat orders date wise

Tags: mysql, sql

The schema of my orders table looks something like this:

```
Orders(Order_ID varchar, Order_NO int, User_ID varchar, Price float, Payment_Status int, Paid_At timestamp)
```

Consider Payment Status as 1 when payment is complete and zero when its not.

Expected Result:

```
Date         New Orders   Repeat Orders  Total of New  Total of Repeat
2015-09-01      4               9              500        1600
2015-09-02      3               5              311         222
```

I tried this query for new orders but it gives only orders from the customers who have placed only one order

```
SELECT date(paid_at) , COUNT(order_no) AS Total_Orders , SUM(price) AS daily_total FROM 
(SELECT * FROM jobs AS D WHERE user_id IN 
    ( SELECT user_id FROM( 
        (SELECT user_id,count(order_no) FROM Orders AS B WHERE user_id IN 
            (SELECT user_id FROM Orders AS A WHERE payment_status = '1' 
                ) GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(order_no) = 1 
            ) AS C
        )
    )   
) 
AS E GROUP BY date(paid_at)
```

As you might have already observed I am a novice to SQL and a little help here will help me improve.

Comment: You have more chance of getting help if you post expected result in your question

Comment: @Veljko89 Added the expected result hope to get help soon.

Comment: You say the query the is to fetch new orders and does that mean payment_status = 1 only? You need to define what according to you is **new order**.

Comment: Please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If you can add the sample data used to create your expected results, you will have more chance of getting help.